# Invalid loop variable type expected Id was GroupMember

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

I am trying to write a trigger that will share a record that is created on a custom object(Split__c) with all the groups the record creator is part of. The reason for this is to share the record created so that others in his group can edit it.

Below is the trigger that I created, but it is throwing some error on line 13 when looping through userToGroupMap map.

```
trigger PartnerCommissionSharing_new on Split__c (after insert, after update) {

    Map<Id, Id> userToGroupMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for(Split__c sc : Trigger.New) { 
        for (GroupMember gm: [SELECT GroupId, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId =:sc.CreatedById] ) {
            userToGroupMap.put(gm.GroupId, gm.UserOrGroupId);
        }
    }


    List<Split__Share> sharesToInsert = new List<Split__Share>();
    for (Split__c split: Trigger.new) {
        for (GroupMember gm: userToGroupMap.keyset()) {
            system.debug('GM Value :' + gm);
            sharesToInsert.add(new Split__Share(ParentId = split.Id, UserOrGroupId = gm, AccessLevel = 'Edit', RowCause = Schema.Split__Share.RowCause.Rep_Sharing__c));                         
        }
    }
    system.degug(sharesToInsert);

    if(sharesToInsert.size() > 0){
        system.debug('Add user group list not empty');
        system.debug(sharesToInsert);
        insert sharesToInsert;
    }


}
```

The error that I receive is

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid loop variable type expected Id was GroupMember at line 86 column 9

Is this approach the way to go sharing? Why do I get this error? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

This error is very straightforward, but it points to a bigger issue. You have asked Salesforce to loop over every `GroupMember` in the set `userToGroupMap.keyset()`. But `userToGroupMap` has type `Map<Id, Id>`: it does not contain `GroupMember` records.

More importantly, though, you're not populating the `Map` in a way that does what you want to do. You appear to be intending to map from one User Id to a number of Group Ids. To do that, you would need a `Map<Id, Set<Id>>`.

Additionally, your code is populating the `Map` backwards:

```
    userToGroupMap.put(gm.GroupId, gm.UserOrGroupId);
```

Here, your *key* is the group Id, and your *value* is the User Id, which is the other way around from what you want.

So if you fixed those issues, you could make the compiler error go away by correctly pulling a `Set<Id>` out of the `Map` to iterate over:

```
for (Id gm: userToGroupMap.get(split.CreatedById)) {
```

Comment: Thank you David. I made some changes to code as below, but it still showing some error. Below is the change I made. <br/>`Map<Id, Set<Id>> userToGroupMap = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();`<br/>Then used the below code to put the values as you said `userToGroupMap.put(gm.UserOrGroupId, gm);` <br/> The error it got is `Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void put(Id, GroupMember) from the type Map<Id,Set<Id>> at line`

Comment: @Gopi, it seems like you need a stronger grounding in how Apex and types work. GroupMember and Id are different types. I'd suggest you work through Trailhead and the Apex Developer Guide to get a better understanding.

Comment: @Gopi GroupMember is a different object type than User or Group. You share records with User or Group records, not with GroupMember records. It's not about how Apex works - you've just made a common mistake.